# Simple Javascript not displaying in Cordova Android app; I have the CSP meta tag, and no CSP errors

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, content-security-policy

In my Cordova Android app, I have a need for some inline javascript for accessing local storage. In testing, I found that I cannot include in my PHP section, any output javascript that will work. Even adding a simple alert script to the beginning of the PHP file does not render in the browser, even though I can see that the code is there in Chrome Dev Tools, Elements. If I put the same script in the app's index.html file, it works.

Also, in the PHP generated section, I have dynamically generated onClick buttons that call a JS function that adds `key-values` to `local storage`. And they work fine. I can see the entries in Chrome Dev Tools.

I have a Content Security Policy meta in the `index.html`, and have tried many combinations, even though no `CSP` errors have ever shown up.

I've been reading and trying suggested fixes for days.

This works:

PHP page:

```
    echo ' <button id='; 
    echo "'$row1[idNodes]'";
    echo ' class="buttonClass" type="button" value=';
    echo "'$row1[idNodes]'";
    echo ' onclick="setStorage(this.value)">';
    echo '<div id=img';
    echo "$row1[idNodes]";
    echo '>';
    echo '<img src=img/cards.png height=20 width=20>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</button> ';
```

inside index.js:

```
function setStorage(val) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
localStorage.setItem(val,"1");
}, false);
var imgswap = "img" + val;
console.log(imgswap);
document.getElementById(imgswap).innerHTML = "<img src=img/shovel.png height=25 width=25>";
}
```

This renders if inside the `index.html` page, but not if inside the php page which, when rendered, is just a string inside the html page itself:

```
<script>
    console.log('Test');
</script>
<?php ...
```

image of the browser output at:
untweeps.org/img/code.jpg
In the browser output image, you can see three scripts are there, but only the one with Test1 works. Test3 is dynamically generated, the other two are static coded.

Not getting any error messages in Dev Tools console. I want to be able to read local storage values with JS and swap the image as in the set function, but I can't get a simple script to run yet. What am I missing?

Comment: so to clarify, your cordova app is a wrapper for an external website that renders using php?

Comment: @MStoner Yes that is correct.